# How to write nested joins with Laravel Query builder?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, join

I have SQL query with next join order (two `JOIN`'s are nested in `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN table1
  JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.document_id
  JOIN table3 ON table3.content_id = table2.id
ON table1.link_id = mytable.link_id
```

How to write this query with Laravel Query builder?

My way:

```
$query = Mytable::select('*')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('table1
        JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.document_id
        JOIN table3 ON table3.content_id = table2.id
    '), 
    'table1.link_id', '=', 'mytable.link_id');
```

It works, but is any way to do it without DB::raw()? Maybe with `$join->nest()`?

Answer (score -1):

The joins aren't nested they are just being used to limit the number of viable records.

`$query = Mytable::select('*')
        ->leftJoin('table1', 'table1.link_id', '=', 'mytable.link_id')
        ->join('table2', 'table2.id', '=', 'table1.document_id')
        ->join('table3 ', 'table3.content_id', '=', 'table2.id');`

Comment: This is not solution. This query will looks like `SELECT * FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.link_id = mytable.link_id JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.document_id JOIN table3 ON table3.content_id = table2.id`